# How to create multiple controls dynamically on click

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to create multiple row of controls (edit box , checkbox and a delete button) in an M.F.C Dialog dynamically at run-time on button click.
And also all the controls added should be displayed in a scroll window.
But unfortunately i can't find any solution to this problem.
Anyone got any ideas?.

I can create a single row of controls. My problem is how to add multiple rows when click the Add Button and also Delete that row by clicking the Delete button on the same row.

It should look somewhat like this after i clicked Add multiple times:

```
|     Edit Box: Type in a Name          |    |Add| 

|Edit Box| |Name 1 (Edit Box)| |Edit Box| |Delete|   ^ 
|Edit Box| |Name 2 (Edit Box)| |Edit Box| |Delete|   | 
|Edit Box| |Name 3 (Edit Box)| |Edit Box| |Delete|   |
etc...                                               v
```

Here is some code of mine:

```
int CSettingDlg::AddControlSet() //Create a single row of controls
{
    int d = 3500;
    if (m_pStrAdd.IsEmpty() == FALSE)
    {
        GetDlgItem(IDC_TEST1)->GetWindowRect(&rect);
        ScreenToClient(&rect);

        EditBox = new CEdit;
        EditBox->Create(WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY, rect, this, d++);

//using the same code above to create 2 more Edit box

        Delete = new CButton;
        Delete->Create(_T("Del"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON, rect, this, d++);
        return TRUE;
    }
}

void CSettingDlg::OnBnClickedAddSettingdlg() //Add button Event handler
{
        UpdateData();
        AddControlSet();
}
```

Comment: If you know, how to create one row of controls, and you want to create multiple rows, execute the code that creates one row multiple times. It is not clear, what the *real* issue is (assuming it isn't the problem that has a trivial solution).

Comment: @IInspectable my real issue is i used GetWindowRect and ScreentoClient to find the desired coordinate to create my control. but when i add those values from ScreentoClient into CRect(), it didn't create anything. so i have to create invisible controls and get coordinates from them, then pass to a rect variable. Then i can create new controls on top of those was hidden. And that's it. i know it's because everytime i click Add, the code in the AddControlSet function will only get the same coordinate everytimes, but i don't know any solution to fix it.

Comment: That is *one* way to store state. I'm sure there are less convoluted ways to persist the information you need, to know where the next line of controls should go. Like storing some identifiable feature of the most recently created row. Regardless, if that is indeed the problem you are trying to solve, you will have to include it in your question. As written, this isn't obvious.

Comment: Perhaps what you actually need is a grid that contains rows of the needed cells. Then your button press just adds a new row. For example the [Dundas Ultimate Grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20183/The-Ultimate-Grid-Home-Page) supports check box and button cell types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in dealing with dynamic creation of control in window environment, you should aware **X** and **Y** direction to draw/create a control on form.

Following is direction of monitor:

[image]

Now lets say you are creating control on form starting with `CRect rect(0, 0, 100, 50);`

Then one control in single row will be place in this location (Edit Box in your case) and when you are adding delete button next to edit box in same row then you should add few co ordinates in **X** axis to get new location of delete button. Hence rect of next location will something like, `CRect rect(105, 0, 205, 50);`

Same way when to move to next row then Y axis should be added with few coordinates to get new location for next row. For example, Next row edit control coordinates will be`CRect rect(0, 55, 100, 105);`

Comment: But i dont know why, when I input my coordinates to CRect() it didn't do anything. I assume it because the coordinate that i input was false. but i literally use everything, from GetWindowRect() + ScreentoClient(), then GetClientRect()+ScreentoClient(). But when i input those coordinates that I found, still i dont see my Edit box anywhere on the Dialog. the only thing i could think of was that the value type of the coordinates (when showing on debug mode) was 'long', but CRect was (int l, int t, int r, int b). This make me so confused.